# How to specify .stopPropagation() in this example?

Tags: jquery, click, hide, stoppropagation

I have used the following code to get "click outside" to close working:

On click the divs show:

```
$('div.topIconNew').click(
    function(){
        $(this).siblings('div.topTip').show();
        $(this).siblings('div.topDrop').slideDown(240);
```

On click outside the divs hide:

```
$('div#wrapper').click(
    function(event){
        $('div.topIconNew, div.topTip, div.topDrop').hide();
    }
);
$('div.topTip, div.topDrop').click(
    function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
);
```

The problem with that above is that the topIconNew .stopPropagation makes it so that once the topTip and topDrop divs are open, they won't close if I click that same topIconNew again (i.e. toggle) or another instance of topIconNew.

NEW EDIT***

Okay, I'm thinking through this and wondering if the solution might be with if statements.

So I ultimately want the following additional code:

```
$('topIconNew').click(
    function(){
        $('div.topTip, div.topDrop').hide();
    }
);
```

However, I want the above to also say to hide topTip and topDrop upon clicking topIconNew only **if** the topTip and topDrop are open **AND** only hide the topTip and topDiv elements that are currently open.

How would I say the above?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I just saw someone on SO implement the 'click anywhere to close pop-up' method in a pretty elegant way; the caveat is that the rest of your page must use `e.stopPropagation()` sparingly.

```
$('div.topIconNew').click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings('div.topTip').show();
    $(this).siblings('div.topDrop').slideDown(240); 

    $(document).one('click', function() {
        $('div.topTip, div.topDrop').hide();
    });

    e.stopPropagation();        

    ...
});
```

Comment: So, you've added .one() to things, so that it only happens once for those elements? I can't seem to get it to work. I'll keep trying and hopefully it works. I'll have to gain a better understanding of the .one() as well and see why it means I have to use .stopPropagation more sparingly. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: To be more specific, the problem I have is that open the initial click of the div, the show and hide canceling each other out still occurs, but just once now. So, once I've done it, it then disables .hide() and shows the div. Unfortunately, I then cannot close upon click outside any longer... as it's exhausted it's ".one()" time.

Comment: .one() just means that it will only execute once.  With that chunk of code above, you don't need the rest.  That alone will open and close the pop up.  The reason you would have to use stopPropagation sparingly is because the click event needs to go all the way up to the document before the pop up would close.  Notice that the .one() is hooking onto the 'document'; and since events bubble up, unless blocked by stopPropagation or 'return false', it will fire that event... but just once.

Comment: Ah okay. I understand that now. However, I'm still having the same issue. When I use that code, it does allow me to open the dropdown on click and close when I click anywhere in the document. However, it's still as if (using the original code) I'm putting "topIconNew" in the stopPropagation. When I click on another one of the "topIconNew" divs, the dropdown won't go away because the hide event is being stopped. There are multiple "topIconNew" divs, but I can't even toggle on the initial one. So, it will either pop up but not close upon clicking the same (or similar) div or not work at all. :(

Comment: Hm, I think there was a bug in my code.  Try removing that e.stopPropagation() from the logic.  At first I thought the click event would be triggered as it is being attached, but that is not the case.

Comment: If I take the e.stopPropagation() out then the dropdowns never open at all because the topIconNew has both .show() and .hide() attached to it on click. These conflict. I'd suspect that if I could open the dropdown, that an additional problem would arise in that when clicking the topTip and topDrop divs, they'd count as "document" and close.

Comment: Try this fiddle, it answers your question directly: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/DydTr/1/